# How to make an async request using redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to make a request to get some user info with redux sagas.
so far I have:

```
function* getUserDetails() {
  const userDetails = axios.get('http://localhost:3004/user').then(response => response)
  yield put({ type: 'USER_DATA_RECEIVED', user: userDetails})
}

function* actionWatcher() {
     yield takeLatest('GET_USER_DATA', getUserDetails)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
   yield all([
   actionWatcher(),
   ]);
}
```

but when I log that out `user` either comes back as `undefined` or `Promise<pending>`. so I tried to add in `yield call(axios stuff in here)`

but that didn't seem to work either

anyone got any ideas either a) how to use `call` properly? and b) how to pass through a payload with the action?

Comment: Have you tried puting `yield put()` into `.then()`?

Comment: what do I do in the then block though? in thunk you just fire the action with the payload, the reducer listens and it's in your state

Comment: I am not familiar with redux, but logic says you should do it like this `.then(response => {yield put({ type: 'USER_DATA_RECEIVED', user: response})})`

Comment: `yield is reserved word`

Comment: @Mirakurun with redux-saga i haven't typically used effects inside the `then` block of a promise, the `call` effect takes care of retrieving the response value from the promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to use the *call* effect in your case would be this:

```
function* getUserDetails() {
  const userDetails = yield call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:3004/user');
  yield put({ type: 'USER_DATA_RECEIVED', user: userDetails})
}
```

The first argument for *call* is the function you want to call, subsequent arguments are arguments you want to pass to the called function.

**Improved Version**

Calls to external APIs can always go wrong, so it's a good practice to safeguard against this by wrapping a try/catch block around the Axios call.

In the catch block, you could, for example, dispatch an action that signals an error, which you can use to show an error message to the user.

```
function* getUserDetails() {
  let userDetails;
  try {
    userDetails = yield call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:3004/user');
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: 'USER_DATA_ERROR', error });
    return;
  }
  yield put({ type: 'USER_DATA_RECEIVED', user: userDetails})
}
```

Comment: you might also want to wrap that call in a `try-catch` depending on how you're doing error handling. the [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args) mention that `call` will resume the generator on a resolved promise, but throw an error on a rejected one.